# Is it possible to ignore @JsonSerialize annotation?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Is it possible to serialize object using Jackson,but ignoring custom serializers registered with annotation `@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)` ?

Rationale:
I want to use Jackson to convert my object to Map, using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(object,Map.class)`.
Currently it does not work, because my class has custom serializer (@JsonSerialize) but misses deserializer. I require custom serializer, and I really do not need and do not want to write deserializer.

`ObjectMapper.convertValue`  uses my serialization then fails at deserialization.

I would like to have ObjectMapper that will just ignore @JsonSerialize and use default serialization logic. Is that possible with Jackson?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103819/4526235) one worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is entirely possible. You could disable annotations on a per ObjectMapper basis, like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
```

For more details check the documentation over at [github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features) or check the examples at [baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

Comment: is there any other way as this solution disabling all the annotations.

Comment: This is like using an elephant tranquilizer on a mouse. Things like `java.beans.ContructorProperties` are also ignored in that case, which on some cases renders this solution unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

you could also disable a spesific annoation by using ignoreJsonTypeInfoIntrospector  and return null for the spsific annoation class;

take a look at the last [github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/133)

```
public class IgnoreJsonUnwrappedAnnotationInspector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
  @Override
  public NameTransformer findUnwrappingNameTransformer(AnnotatedMember member) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

also take a look here for more [detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056716/disable-jackson-mapper-for-a-particular-annotation)

another solution is to create more ObjectMapper instances for the different scenarios.