# How to ignore only @JsonSerialize annotations in combination with DefaultTyping

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have seen the many questions and answers about [ignoring certain annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056716/disable-jackson-mapper-for-a-particular-annotation), or even disabling all annotations:

```java
.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)
```

But

1. the first solution defeats DefaultTyping (types don't end up in the serialized JSON and
2. the second solution defeats many useful annotations, of which the most critical to us: `java.beans.ConstructorProperties`.

How can I ignore `@JsonSerialize` and still have typeinfo in my resulting JSON while still supporting other annotations such as `ConstructorProperties`?

Here's what I have so far:

```java
private static ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        @Override
        protected TypeResolverBuilder<?> _findTypeResolver(MapperConfig<?> config, Annotated ann, JavaType baseType) {
            if (ann.hasAnnotation(JsonSerialize.class) || ann.hasAnnotation(JsonDeserialize.class)) {
                return StdTypeResolverBuilder.noTypeInfoBuilder(); // or null
            }
            return super._findTypeResolver(config, ann, baseType);
        }
    });
    return mapper;
}
// or the same config using a JsonMapper builder
```

But this still processes `@JsonSerialize` for some reason. I'm on jackson 2.10.0.pr3.

---

The real problem I'm facing is that I'm serializing 3rd party objects, which contain provided `@JsonSerialize` for unrelated purposes, but without defining `@JsonDeserialize`. Even though they're perfectly serializable without these annotations, they end up blocking our deserialization. At the same time I don't know upfront which classes they are, so these should be encoded in the resulting JSON. Furthermore, some of these objects are generated with Lombok resulting in no-arg constructors annotated with `java.beans.ConstructorProperties` which Jackson can deal with fine under normal circumstances.

It's the above combination of configuration I'm not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector#findSerializer` method:

```
class SkipSerializersJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    private final List<Class> classesToSkip = new ArrayList<>();

    public SkipSerializersJacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        classesToSkip.add(YourClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object findSerializer(Annotated a) {
        if (classesToSkip.contains(a.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }

        return super.findSerializer(a);
    }
}
```

It should allow you to skip `JsonSerialize` annotation and keep type.